# Como puedo manejar la fecha en Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

Hola estoy haciendo un contador regresivo con el fremwork simplyconuntdown de javascript el problema es que la fecha limite a la que quiero que llegue regresiva mente la obtengo por ajax por que esta almacenada en una base de datos pero es que no se como hacer para pasar esa fecha de php a javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el código javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.ver').click(function(){

      $('.modal3').css({'display': 'block'});
    
    let id = $('.ver').attr('id');

     $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          data: {id: id},
          url: 'contador.php',
          success: function(response) {

                    let info = JSON.parse(response);

                    console.log(info);   

    simplyCountdown('.cuenta', {
    year: 2021, // required
    month: 4, // required
    day: 2, // required
    hours: 31, // Default is 0 [0-23] integer
    minutes: 60, // Default is 0 [0-59] integer
    seconds: 60, // Default is 0 [0-59] integer
    words: { //words displayed into the countdown
        days: 'Dia',
        hours: 'Hora',
        minutes: 'Minuto',
        seconds: 'Segundo',
        pluralLetter: 's'
    },
    plural: true, //use plurals
    inline: false, //set to true to get an inline basic countdown like : 24 days, 4 hours, 2 minutes, 5 seconds
    inlineClass: 'simply-countdown-inline', //inline css span class in case of inline = true
    // in case of inline set to false
    enableUtc: true, //Use UTC as default
    onEnd: function() {
        
        return; 
    }, //Callback on countdown end, put your own function here
    refresh: 1000, // default refresh every 1s
    sectionClass: 'simply-section', //section css class
    amountClass: 'simply-amount', // amount css class
    wordClass: 'simply-word', // word css class
    zeroPad: false,
    countUp: false
});
   
            }

        });       

  });

 //boton de cierre modal1
  $('.epa').click(function(){

         
          $('.modal3').css({'display': 'none'});
          setTimeout(function() { location.href="index.php"; }, 500);
      
     });
```

Y este es el código PHP

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';

  $id=$_POST['id'];

         $p = "SELECT * FROM registro where id = '$id'";
         $consult = mysqli_query($conexion,$p);

         mysqli_close($conexion);

         $fila= mysqli_num_rows($consult);

         if ($fila > 0) {
            
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consult);
            echo json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            exit;
         }

         echo "error";
         exit;
?>
```

y lo que quiero es que los datos de ***Pago*** lo pueda poner en la variables ***year month day*** del simplycountdown

***Esta parte no es relevante para nada***

esta parte la pongo porque la pagina dice que es mas codigo que texto entonces escribo esto para poder publicarlo

Comment: Agrega un ejemplo de cómo llega la fecha. Del __console.log(info)__ que estás haciendo.

Answer (score 0):

Si la fecha la tienes en php en formato texto `YYYY-MM-DD` y necesitas los datos en javascript para cada campo individual Año mes y día puedes separarlos con split:

```js
var response = '2021-12-24'; /* esta es la variable donde recibes la fecha del ajax*/

var date = response.split("-");

console.log('año: '+date[0]+' mes: '+date[1]+' dia: '+date[2]);
```

y entonces usas esos valores en el plugin simplyconuntdown.